# Post revisions disappeared (for some posts)

Tags: posts, revisions

I have noticed today that I don't see post revisions anymore, and I don't see it for all posts, custom posts, pages... null.

I've checked all possibilities that I knew:

- WP_POST_REVISIONS
- turning off all plugins
- changing to a default template (twenty sixteen)
- checking if posts support `revisions`
- checking screen options if they can be enabled - no such checkbox
- in the wp_posts table filtered by `post_type = revision` I see only a few revisions - the last one is two months old

What else could be done to get my revisions back?
Currently I'm using Wordpress version 4.8

**UPDATE**

I have to tell you one more thing, I found out that when revisions stopped working, my co-programmer turned of `support revisions` for posts, now when he turned them on back again I have noticed that revisions show up for all new posts and doesn't work for any of the posts created when `support revisions` were removed.

I have compared in the DB the "old" post with the "new" and I cannot find any real differences between them. There must be some attribute responsible for this but I cannot find it.

Does anyone know what prevents the old posts from supporting the revisions?

Comment: This actually looks like a bug to me, though I don't see anything for it in trac (https://core.trac.wordpress.org/component/Revisions). I guess the workaround for the time being would be to duplicate the old posts so that you can have revisions for them, though I know that's a pain.

Comment: Actually after revising a post a second time, now revisions show. So maybe after enabling, it takes 2 revisions to start showing. Though it did store the other revision in the database, so it's weird that it didn't display.

Answer (score 1):

Check your database to see if the revisions are still there. Use phpmyadmin or another database tool and go to wp_posts table and search for `post_type = revision`. If they are not there, they are gone. A lot of "optimization" plugins remove post revisions for you. I would check if any of your plugins has that functionality.

If you still see then in the database, than you have another issue at hand, and will need further troubleshooting to figure out what's going on.

Comment: As I said - they are there in the DB, but only the ones two months old, but I don't really care about the old revisions. I need them to start working now, but all the options and information regarding revisions is gone. When I edit  any post now, the revisions aren't neither displayed nor saved in the DB.

Comment: Post revisions can be turned off altogether. See if that's not the case by checking if this line is in wp_config.php define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', false );

Comment: As I noticed in my question I've checked `WP_POST_REVISIONS` already :(

Comment: Damn it! I should learn how to read. Sorry.